# How to display FormField content on html page?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I was creating a competition form where I want user to add question in that. The question will be added if the user click's on Add Question button on that.

I was trying this in forms.py

```
class CompetitionEntryForm(FlaskForm):
    question = StringField('Question', validators=[DataRequired()])
    option1 = StringField('Option 1', validators=[DataRequired()])
    option2 = StringField('Option 2', validators=[DataRequired()])
    option3 = StringField('Option 3', validators=[DataRequired()])
    answer = StringField('Answer', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=2)])

class CompetitionForm(FlaskForm):
    competition = FieldList(FormField(CompetitionEntryForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Host')
```

main.py Code:

```
@app.route("/competition", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def competition():
    user_competition = [{"name": "First Address"},
                  {"name": "Second Address"}]
    form = CompetitionForm(competition=user_competition)
    return render_template('competition.html', title='Competition', form=form)
```

competition.html Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {% for competition_entry_form in form.competition %}
        {{ competition_entry_form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ competition_entry_form.name }}
        <!-- There must be some code here to display the form. But I don't know how to do that -->
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But the issue I don't know how to display it on the web page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i had done:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {% for competition_entry_form in form.competition %}
        {{ competition_entry_form.hidden_tag() }}
        <!-- Add this from below -->
        {{ competition_entry_form.question }}
        {{ competition_entry_form.option1 }}
        {{ competition_entry_form.option2 }}
        <!-- and so on -->
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```